# Register Keyup and Keydown on Alert() popup

Tags: javascript, dom, window, alert, addeventlistener

I have a script that tracks keys pressed down in a method like so

```
this.keyMap[keyCode] = event.type == 'keydown';
```

I've bound the function that maps the keys to the window object with :

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(){ 
    global_formMovementManager.mapKey(event); 
}, true);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(){ 
    global_formMovementManager.mapKey(event); 
}, true);
```

Currently, when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Enter</kbd> it submits the form, and on an error an `alert()` is displayed. The problem is that when the alert is displayed - if the user lets go of any buttons it is not registered by the `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` window event listeners.

From what I understand `alert()` is a method of the `window` object : `window.alert()`, so I am surprised the listeners are not functioning.

Is there a method to bind event listeners to the `alert()` popup?

Comment: Attaching events is only possible for the DOM elements present in the markup but not for the elements which are thrown by javascript engine.
Here if you want to handle events, then instead of showing alerts you need to show modal dialogs with errors. As modal dialog is an element event will get attached.

Comment: @Bkjain655 wouldn't that logic imply that it is not possible to attach an event listener to the window object?

Comment: actually yes, you made me confused :). Upvoting the question.
But I guess it should be something related to Events Class.